# How to implement generic sort based on map key inside java bean?

Tags: java, sorting, collections

i have a java bean named document that has a map:

```
private Map<String,Object> customProperties;
```

this map is filled with keys like: name,id,title,....etc

and the map is filled generic too, so you can't predicate the keys.

and i want to make generic sort based on a key so that i can sort list of document objects by name or id or title.

all the examples i saw is about make generic sort by property name inside the java bean but i couldn't find any example to sort by key inside map in the object.

i want to be able to do something like:

```
Collections.sort(documents, new GenericComparator("key_id", true));
// where key_id is a key inside the customProperties map; 
// so that all the documents will be ordered based on the key_id
```

please advise how to do so

Comment: Could you show what you have so far? What do you mean by "property name inside the class"?

Comment: Why don't you use the `Comparator` interface and override `compare()`?

Comment: @pedromss sorry i meant property inside java bean

Comment: @TheLostMind, i can't figure out how to do that, that's why i asked

Comment: See my extended answer.

Comment: I hope I've caught up with all your late additions and changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
private Map<String,Object> customProperties = new TreeMap<>();
```

And the entries can be retrieved in the sort order of the key (String values).

A more dynamic approach is  possible using implementations of Comparator:

```
public class Bean {
    private String id;
    private int    value;
    //...
}

public class GenComp<B, C extends Comparator<B>> {
    public void sort( B[] beans, C comp ){
    Arrays.sort( beans, comp );
    }
    public void sort( List<B> list, C comp ){
        Collections.sort( list, comp );
    }
}

class CompById implements Comparator<Bean> {
    public int compare(Bean b1, Bean b2){
        return b1.getId().compareTo( b2.getId() );
    }
}
```

You can, just as well, access a property stored in a Map within the Bean:

```
    public int compare(Bean b1, Bean b2){
        return b1.getProperty( "id" ).compareTo( b2.getProperty( "id" ) );
    }
```

And to call:

```
Bean[] beans = new Bean[]{ ... };
GenComp<Bean,CompById> gc = new GenComp<>();
gc.sort( beans, new CompById() );
```

Actually, class GenComp is just a placeholder in case you'd like to have a different API, as it is, you might call Arrays.sort or Collections.sort without an additional layer.

Comment: and how to sort list of document java beans based on generic key inside the customProperties map  ?

Comment: yes.. this *would* work but don't you think that it would be better in terms of extensibility, if he used a custom comparator?

Comment: @TheLostMind, how it will work ? can you please give sample of how can i call the sorting method in this case ?

Comment: @Mahmoud - Your map will be sorted in *natural order* .

Comment: @TheLostMind, can you please look at the original post, i added sample code of what i want to do

Comment: @Mahmoud - ya.. I got it.. yes, you can use a custom comparator and override compare to achieve that.. But what about the other keys that don't match your *generic* criteria.. you will have to handle them too.

Comment: @TheLostMind, can you please give a sample of the compare method in this case ? i can't figure out how to do this part

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the [Comparable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface and overwite the [compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) method :

```
class Keys implements Comparable{
    public int compareTo(String anotherKey){
         //here you can compare the keys based on the number in the Key
    }
}
```

Comment: the keys in the map are not numbered, it can be 'id' or 'name' or 'title'

Comment: Then what do want to base on when sorting the key?

Comment: can you please look at the original post, i added sample code of what i want to do